# Motorization of a Shaft

Tags: motor

I know this is an awkward one, but need some answers. Is it a good practice to fix/lock the shaft of a motor, and consequently the body of motor shall start rotating?

Essentially, there is a shaft which has a hollow diameter. I have to mount the motor inside the shaft (the outer diameter of the motor shall be equal to the hollow diameter of the shaft), and rotate the shaft as my final product?

Any recommendations about suitable motors, or any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough specifics on the mechanical dimensions to give an answer but in gneral aside from the wiring problems, you'd have to figure out how to balance the motor body, otherwise the bearings would fail pretty quickly.  Also the inner stationary shaft has to be connected to something outside of the shaft to counteract the rotational force.  If its a long tube then you have additional vibration modes to deal with (which are in the mechanical engineering department).

Comment: Look at model airplane "outrunner" motors.  Like @isdi said, bearings will be an issue, but an outrunner is already kinda-sorta inside out in the way you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In industrial applications, the type of motor described is called an "outer-rotor" or "inside-out" motor. Brushless DC motors of that type used for model airplanes and small drones are called "out runners." Various manufacturers of industrial motors supply custom-designed stators and rotors to machine manufacturers for incorporation in driven equipment. It may be possible to purchase standard motors and modify them to fit your requirements, but that is likely to be very challenging. You may not find a standard motor that can be modified to suit your needs.